# Adding results from a for loop to a dictionary , and then appending to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm aware that this is really simply , but I'm struggling with this. Basically I want to add the results of a for loop inside a dicionary, so i can work the results on another function, which i can print the desired field based on the key value,

Example:

```
    i = 0
    b = 0
    cc = []
    while True:
        i += 1
        b += 1
        abc = {b: i}
        cc.append(abc)
        if i == 3:
            break
```

Result : `[{1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}]`

So, the expected result would be `[{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}]`

This is for python 2.7

Comment: Is your only issue with the result that the keys are numbers instead of strings?

Comment: Why put a dictionary in a list if you're only going to be having one dict in the list? Why not make `cc` the dict instead

Comment: On a side note, your `while` logic is bugging me... As in the answer below, you can use a `for` loop or at the very least, write your condition in the `while` loop : `while i < 3 :`. :)

Comment: @Daneel 10h of overnight work do that to people, I'm aware that this is really something that is simple but i can't think straight right now. But I will only leave the office when I solve this.

Comment: @Thales Pereira Check out the answer below, I think it does what you're looking for !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your expected outcome, I would suggest this:

```
cc = []
for i in range(0,3):
    cc.append({str(i): i})
```

But please note that you do **NOT** get a dictionary at the end of this loop... What you get is a list of dictionaries, each dictionary featuring only one key-value pair... `[{'1':1},{'2':2}]` is not the same as `{'1':1, '2':2}` and you will probably have problems using such a list of dictionaries.

So my guess is you want something more along the lines of this:

```
cc = dict()
for i in range(0,3):
    cc[str(i)] = i
```

Please tell me if I misunderstood your problem or if you need more explanation for the solutions.

Comment: Your second example worked perfectly, but if i try to iterate  the cc dict with for k,v in cc  i get this: http://paste.ofcode.org/huid6kccw59pFxtTCJsrna

Comment: @ThalesPereira use this `for k,v in cc.iteritems()`

Comment: @Pavan I managed to get in there, thanks for that Pavan. Now i can go home and sleep.